# Do selection of text only if contains

Tags: php, regex

ive been trying to find something working in my case. The thing that im trying to do is clearly select text when there are "c." so the text is c. Troy , Rome .Basically i want to select c., the text + the "," symbol only if "c." is present. Please help.

The code i came up with so far is [с.]+[^,]* it kinda works, but its not selecting "," and is not doing it only if "c." exists.

P.S. With the help of Anubhava in the comments we came up with ^(?:с|гр).[^,\n]*, which aims to check if с. exists and select before the "," now we aim at when гр. exists to select after ",".

Thanks for all the effort!!

Basically in the first case it highlights "с. Глозене", but in the second case where гр. is present i would like to select the content after the , which in the example is "14-ти километър".
Example url: https://regex101.com/r/BtQsVV/1

Regex Flavor - PHP.

Comment: Works awesome, how can i select the text after "," under the same conditions ?

Comment: Oh sorry, so here is the example https://regex101.com/r/cO8lqs/23425 i just tested it with cyrrilic C and it is not working. I want to delete everything, but "Ловеч"

Comment: Works awesome, can i extend it to like something else if, so if instead of с. we have гр. then select and delete after "," ? Thank you for your help btw!

Comment: Nope it is not working :/ https://regex101.com/r/cO8lqs/23428

Comment: It is working fine: https://regex101.com/r/cO8lqs/23429 (you need `m` flag)

Comment: Oh yes thanks, but in the second case where гр. is existing i want to select after the "," is it possible ?

Comment: please don't create requirements via comments. Edit your question and post all requirements at once

Comment: If you can add some sample data in ur question and show valid/invalid matches then I can assist further

Comment: Also what is your regex flavor? is it PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex for your task:

```
^(?:с\.[^,]*,|гр\.[^,]*,\h*\K.*)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BtQsVV/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `с\.`: Match `с.`
  - `[^,]*,`: Match 0+ non-comma characters followed by a `,`
  - `|`: OR
  - `гр\.`: Match `гр.`
  - `[^,]*,`: Match 0+ non-comma characters followed by a `,`
  - `\h*`: Match 0+ whitespace characters
  - `\K`: reset match info
  - `.*`: Match 0+ of any characters till end
- `)`: End non-capture group

Comment: Thank you for all the effort and patience with me!! Everything is working amazingly now!